# Unable to receive firebase messaging until i kill the app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know that it has a lot of questions about this theme, but no one works in my project, and I don't know why.

I'm using RNF on my project to handle push notification. Everything is set up correctly, but to get notification working, I have to first kill the app, relaunch, and only then I receive notification.

This issue happen in both ios and android.

Here is a sample of my code (bootstrapNotification.js)

```
async function requestUserPermission(): Promise<any> {
  if (!messaging().isDeviceRegisteredForRemoteMessages) {
    await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
  }

  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  return enabled;
}

async function getToken(): Promise<any> {
  return messaging()
    .getToken()
    .then((token) => {
      return token;
    });
}

export default async function startNotification() {
  const enabled = await requestUserPermission();
  const token = await getToken();
  NotificationApi.subscribe(token).subscribe();
  if (token && enabled) {
    log.info('onMessage started');
    messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      log.info('A new FCM message arrived!', remoteMessage);
    });

    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
      log.info('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    });
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((remoteMessage) => {
      log.info(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage,
      );
    });
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then((remoteMessage) => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          log.info(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage,
          );
        }
      });
  } else {
    log.error('Error token or authrorization');
  }
}
```

some information :

```
  "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.4.2",
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.63.3",
```